# surface integral (curl F n ds)

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $F$ be a vector field and let $n$ be normal vector of the closed surface $S$. Then show that $$\iint_S \mathrm{curl} \ F \cdot n\ ds=0. $$

I need help on this exercise.

Comment: Did you try use the Divergence Theorem and the fact that $div\circ curl\equiv0$?

Comment: i got the idea.

Comment: You'd better have the condition that $S$ is a *closed* surface!!

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: The divergence of a curl vector field is always $0$. So just relate your integral to the volume integral over your surface if you catch my drift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can relate the surface integral of a vector field over a closed surface to a volume integral using the divergence theorem (actually a result from the general Stoke's theorem).  Remember that the curl of a vector field is a vector field itself i.e. $\vec{V}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F}$.  Divergence theorem:

$$  \iiint\limits_\Omega\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{V}d\tau=\iint\limits_{\partial\Omega}\vec{V}\cdot d\vec{S} $$

$$  \iiint\limits_\Omega\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F})d\tau=\iint\limits_{\partial\Omega} (\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{F})\cdot d\vec{S} $$

Now, whats the divergence of the curl?